# Getting pg_restore error 1 when running pg:pull on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am trying to copy the database from our staging server onto my local machine and I'm having some issues. This was working 2 months ago flawlessly and when I tried to use it again today I'm getting an issue.

I am using this command:

`heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL my_app_db -a myApp`

And at the end of the logs I get this:

```
pg_dump: reading subscriptions
pg_dump: reading large objects
pg_dump: reading dependency data
pg_dump: saving encoding = UTF8
pg_dump: saving standard_conforming_strings = on
pg_dump: saving search_path = 
pg_dump: saving database definition
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header
pg_dump: dumping contents of table "public.addresses"
 ▸    pg_restore errored with 1
```

I've tried updating my postgresql package but they're the same on Heroku and my local machine:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

```
$ heroku run psql --version -a myApp
Running psql --version on ⬢ myApp... up, run.5796 (Hobby)
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

I've always dropped the database locally before doing the pull:

```
$ psql postgres
postgres=# DROP DATABASE my_app_db;
postgres=# \q
```

Update 1:

Looks like I have a `pg_dump` and `pg_pull` version mismatch:

```
$ pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 10.13 (Ubuntu 10.13-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

```
$ heroku run pg_dump --version -a myApp
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

```
$ pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 10.13 (Ubuntu 10.13-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

```
$ heroku run pg_restore --version -a myApp
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

What I saw on the internet is that it should be updated by installing the latest postgresql. For some reason two of them aren't updated even with the latest PostgreSQL version.

**Solution to resolve the issue:**

As `clemoun` pointed out, I must've had multiple psql versions running. I saw what I have with:

```
$ pg_lsclusters
```

Then uninstalled version `10` and `11` with:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove postgresql-10 postgresql-11
```

After that dropped the clusters:

```
$ sudo pg_dropcluster 10 main
$ sudo pg_dropcluster 11 main
```

And logged out and in.

Comment: Please post also output of `pg_dump --version` and `pg_restore --version`. Are you sure that `pull` is using the same PostgreSQL version ?

Comment: @pifor done. Under the `Update 1` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have at the same time :

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

and

```
$ pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 10.13 (Ubuntu 10.13-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

makes me think you have several versions of PostgreSQL installed on your computer.

Try typing :

```
sudo find /usr -wholename '*/bin/postgres'
```

and you might find out you have both PostgreSQL versions 10.13 and 12.3 installed.
For some reason it's the 10.13 version of pg_restore that runs and Heroku requires that you use a version above 10.3
=> Your 12.3 version should do the trick

Try uninstalling version 10.13 of Postgresql, leaving you computer with version 12.3 only. Thus pg_restore will run on version 12.3

Comment: Thanks! I've uninstalled those old postgresql versions and had to drop the clusters for them. I've written the steps how-to in the question.